# How to get user's name from user_id in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have 2 table 1st `fund` 2nd `users` I have registered member name in `users` table while in `fund` table `user_id` of registered member. I  want to show users name in a table where I am able to show its `user_id`.

```
<div class="deposit-body">
    <table class="table main-table">
        <tbody>
            <tr class="head">
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Currency</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
            </tr>
            @foreachFund::with('user')->where('created_at', '>', Carbon::now()->subHours(24))->orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(10)->get()
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $fund->user_id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $fund->updated_at}}</td>
                    <td><strong>{{$basic->currency}}</strong></td>
                    <td><strong>{{ $fund->total }}</strong></td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I have pasted following code to my Fund model. But it is not working.

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id'); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `relationship` to access user object.

```
@foreach(Fund::with('user')->where('created_at', '>', Carbon::now()->subHours(24))->orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(10)->get() as $fund)
 <tr>
        <td>{{ $fund->user->name }}</td>
 </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: i have used but it says . trying to get property of non-object

Comment: try with updated code, and try to move your query to a controller, you should not query in a view template

Comment: then use namespace as prefix as  `App\Fund::with('user')->where('created_at', '>', Carbon::now()->subHours(24))->orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(10)->get()`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like not all funds have `user_id` filled. In this case, you should use the [`optional()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-optional) helper.

Move the logic to controller:

```
$funds = Fund::with('user')->where('created_at', '>', Carbon::now()->subHours(24))->orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(10)->get();
return view('your.view', compact('funds'));
```

Then in the view:

```
@foreach ($funds as $fund)
    {{ optional($fund->user)->name }}
@endforeach
```